# evaluating a rank based on several variables (Game Programming)

Tags: language-agnostic

I am designing a fairly simple space combat desktop game with no graphics, but i want the back end to be robust enough for lots of expansion. I want to rank three different aspects of a ship's capabilities on a scale from 1 to 100 (although i'm willing to reconsider these numbers.)

For instance, i have the hitpoint section of the ship class as follows:

```
// section private defense
float baseHull;
float hullMod;
float baseArmor;
float armorMod
float baseSheild;
float ShieldMod;
float miscMod = 1.0; // this can be “rarer ship types, i.e. elites or bosses or stations     or the rich.**
```

these can be any arbitrary value, for now. i haven't designed anything to fit in the variables yet, because I'm trying to figure out how to rank the ships based on these sections... one each for movement, hitpoints, and offensive capabilities. As an added bonus, a global ranking would be nice too. the hitpoints section as above would just be "hitpoints" on the screen, like 50,000HP for a moderate support class ship and 100 for the space shuttles we have on earth.

the ranking would determine likelihood of winning a fight, and the "XP" rewarded for winning a fight. Adding them all up wouldn't work, because a ship with 10 meters of uranium plating isn't necessarily better than one with 1 meter of lead plating and shields. for reference, earth clothing would be a rank 1, an M1A1 tank would be like a 5, and the death star would be up around 40-50ish.

I've been searching for ways to do this with real world data, but i am neither a mathematics whiz or a statistician. is there a way to weight this into a handy function? is it possible to reverse the function to say input a value and have it assign the internals (this would be really cool, but not necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple way to combine those variables to a total hitpoint value would be:

```
hitpoints = baseHull * hullMod + baseArmor * armorMod + baseShield * shieldMod;
```

You could then assign, say, values between 0 and 100 for the base values determining "how much" of hull, armor, and shield they have, and values between 1 and 10 for the modifying values, which define "how strong" each item is.

Calculating the winner of a fight could be done like this, for example:

```
totalPoints = ship1Points + ship2Points;
ship1won = (rand() % totalPoints) < ship1Points;
```

Where the points of the ships are some values calculated by the hitpoints and the offense values of the ships. So you calculate the total points of the two combating ships and pick a random number between 0 and the total points. If `ship1points` is, say, 20, and `ship2points` is 50, ship 1 has the possibility of winning of 20 / 70. To reduce the probability even more (say you want to be more sure that the stronger ship wins), you could multiply both points by a constant or square them before the final calculation.

Comment: ah, using the products might work. it's a general case, the ranking, obviously the nuts and bolts of the fight might play out different, that's the intrigue of a roleplaying style space game (i forgot that part!) i'll start a catalog of ships in the next couple of days and see what values are sane and try your method!

The actual fights are going to play out like escape velocity/S.P.A.Z. or borderlands (they have shields that you can pierce/disable on enemies) - so the actual values become relevant. this is just to determine a Spock style "chances of success."